# How do I prevent PyQT TableWidget stretching past the number of rows I have specified

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I've created a very simple table widget that has 1 selectable and 2 non-selectable rows. I want to then restrict the table so that it doesn't stretch to fill all available space.
[image]

The table should stop after the "Other" entry rather than continuing to fill the space.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "stretch to fill": is that the only widget? Is there a layout? Also, is the table editable, or could the contents change programmatically? And are you actually sure you need a QTableWidget for this? That seems like a "wizard", and using a table for that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: The color is faint, but looking very close on the image, we can see that the `QTableWidget` *gray border* stretches to the bottom of the image area. If that's what you want to prevent, you could insert the `QTableWidget` inside a `QVBoxLayout`, and add a stretch at the end of the vbox to fill the remaining space.

Comment: @CarlHR - I'd added stretch but I'd added it incorrectly to the horizontal layout rather than the vertical one that contained it. All good now. Musicamente - contents could change but not whilst the user is on that screen, e.g. if I add future email providers in future then it will grow. This is a wizard but I've done it using QStackedWidget because I want to slide between pages. In either implementation I would prefer a table vs radio buttons purely from an aesthetic perspective. Was there something else that you were thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QTableWidget is not a good choice for such an interface: if you use a table with the left item for the text, then you're forced to always compute the proper spanning of that cell, which might not work well if the text requires more vertical space than the contents on the right.

Consider your case: what would have happened to the text if you only had *one* item on the right?

Also, what if you have much more elements? When the user scrolls the view to see the other options, then the text would scroll along with it.

A proper choice would be, instead, using a standard text widget (possibly, a QLabel, but be aware about known [layout issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues)) and QListWidget for the contents.

In order to properly achieve the result, we have to consider some important aspects.

First, all Qt scroll areas are expanding by default (which is the main point of your problem), and also implement various aspects of widgets in order to ensure that they always have a proper size by showing as much content as possible, and provide a common, expected behavior.

The default behavior of a layout when adding a widget is to let it occupy the whole space of its layout cell: if a widget has a size hint of `50x50`, the layout allows for `100x100`, and the widget size policy allows it to *grow* (which is **not** the same as *expand*), then the widget will occupy the whole `100x100` size.

To prevent this, you can specify the `alignment` flag to `addWidget()`, and in this way the widget will only use its minimum size hint of the alignment direction; considering the case above:

- if you use `alignment=Qt.AlignTop`, the widget will be aligned on top, and will have a size of `100x50`;
- for a `Qt.AlignLeft` alignment, the widget will be on the left, and sized `50x100`;

Ok, but what now?
A common solution is to override the `sizeHint()` and return a proper height based on the contents. For instance:

```py
class MyList(QListWidget):
    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if self.count():
            height = sum(self.sizeHintForRow(r) for r in range(self.count()))
            hint.setHeight(height + self.frameWidth() * 2)
        return hint
```

<sup>Note: the `self.frameWidth() * 2` considers the border margins around the scroll area; see the related note below.</sup>

This "works", but has some issues. For instance, if items are inserted/removed *after* the widget is added to an already active layout, the hint is not considered. So we also need to notify the layout whenever the widget size hint changes, by calling [`updateGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry):

```py
class MyList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.updateGeometry)
        self.model().rowsRemoved.connect(self.updateGeometry)
```

Unfortunately, still not enough: we still can get a view that is bigger than the contents, because there are not enough items: Qt scroll areas also return a valid [minimum size hint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) (normally, `75x75`), meaning that if you have contents that are *smaller* than that size, the view will still be bigger than you would hope.

Now, Qt item views actually implement a [`sizeAdjustPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop) property, which results in returning a different size from `sizeHint()` based on the view's contents and eventually adjust the whole layout.

Even this partially works, though, because of the `minimumSizeHint` property explained above. To avoid this, then we can just revert to the default behavior of QWidget, which is to return an invalid QSize from `minimumSizeHint()`.

We're almost there.
Qt scroll areas also have a [`viewportSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportSizeHint) function, that returns a basic size hint of the *viewport*, which is the hint of the *visible* area in which the contents are visible and scroll may happen. This is what the `sizeAdjustPolicy` property above becomes important: the scroll area uses the `viewportSizeHint` to compute the overall size hint, including contents, margins and scroll bars (if always/already shown).

Finally, there's a peculiar case: when an item is wide enough to require the horizontal scroll bar. While this is not really a problem when many items are shown, it can be annoying when they are few, and especially if there's only one. On systems that use scroll bars that have heights similar to the font size, the result is that the item becomes almost (if not completely) invisible.

While we could just ignore all the problems above just for this situation, and just implement `sizeHint()`, this is not a very good solution if we don't have absolute knowledge of the possible contents of the view. Since we cannot use *any* of the hint-related functions to know *if* the scroll bar is needed (we'd risk recursion), a possibility is to implement the [`heightForWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#heightForWidth) function (which is normally called *after* size hint calls) and return a proper height considering the possible presence of the scroll bar. Note that this *must* also consider the [`frameWidth`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameWidth-prop) property (the "border") as did above; this is normally not an issue, *unless* you specify different border size properties in a Qt Style Sheet (e.g. a left border that is different from the top one).

Ok, we're probably done.
Here is a basic code that shows the proper implementation of all the above:

```py
class AdjustList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(self.AdjustToContents)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self.sizeHint().height()
        if (self.horizontalScrollBarPolicy() == Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded
            and width < self.sizeHintForColumn(0) + self.frameWidth() * 2 
        ):
            height += self.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()
        return height

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize()

    def viewportSizeHint(self):
        hint = super().viewportSizeHint()
        if self.count():
            height = sum(self.sizeHintForRow(r) for r in range(self.count()))
            hint.setHeight(height)
        return hint
```

And here is a possible result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

The code for the image above, just for test and explanation purposes:

```py
from random import choice, randrange
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class AdjustList(QListWidget):
    # as above

class WizardPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,  text, choices):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(420, 300)
        self.descriptionLabel = QLabel(text, 
            wordWrap=True, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.choiceList = AdjustList()
        self.choiceList.addItems(choices)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(hLayout)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.descriptionLabel, stretch=3)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.choiceList, stretch=4, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        # just for explanation purposes
        for i in range(1, 11):
            QTimer.singleShot(i * 1000, lambda:
                self.choiceList.addItem(
                    ''.join(choice(letters) for l in range(randrange(1, 80))
                        ).capitalize()
                ))


app = QApplication([])
words = [''.join(choice(letters) for l in range(randrange(10))) for w in range(25)]
text = 'Some random text ' + ' '.join(words)
items = ['Google', 'iCloud', 'Other']
wiz = WizardPage(text, items)
wiz.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: This answer is awesome. I really appreciate the explanation, actually helping me to learn how to get to the answer as well as having the right answer! Also looked in to QWizard as suggested and think that it may be the way to go for what I'm looking for. Pretty sure I will also be able to get some page transitions / animations going with enough reading!

Comment: @peetysmith You're very welcome, answering also helped me to finally refine the techniques used to achieve the result, which is a requirement that sometimes pops up. And, actually, the reference to QWizard was just a hint, but that's probably what you'll need. Of course, in that case you'll also need to properly consider the restrictions of the actual QWizardPage class.